# jsonpath: add 2 elements and then compare

Tags: javascript, jsonpath

Given the following `json` data:

```
[
 {
   "item":"T1",
   "size":10,
   "offset":3
  },
  {
    "item":"T2",
    "size":20,
    "offset":5
  }
]
```

query expr: `$.[? ((@size + @offset)<15)].item`

the query returns nothing. Anything wrong? it looks like `(@size + @offset)` is not supported. If so, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to try this instead:

$.[? ((@.size + @.offset)<15)].item

Note the dot after each @ sign.

Answer (score 0):

With DefiantJS, you can execute XPath on JSON structures.
http://defiantjs.com/

At this site (http://defiantjs.com/#xpath_evaluator), you can paste in your JSON data and try out standard XPath. I have tested your json data and tested this XPath expression, which works as expected:

```
//*[size + offset > 15]/item
```

DefiantJS extends the global object JSON with an additional method; "search" and in javascript, it looks like this:

```
var res = JSON.search(json_data, "//*[size + offset > 15]/item");
console.log(res[0]);
// T2
```